# Styling the Highlighting in CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to change the background color and foreground color (or text color) of the highlighted portion in a HTML page? In another words, customize the hightlighting of our Webpage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only with CSS3 (modern browsers only, obviously), if you want to use pure CSS.

http://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for these styles:

- `::selection` (General)
- `::-moz-selection` (For Mozilla)
- `::-webkit-selection` (For Webkit)

**More Info:**

- http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selection.html

Comment: +1 for including the actual information rather than just linking externally